# How test dedicated bandwidth - 10 Mbps

Tags: bandwidth

Level 3 has recently installed a dedicated internet conection (10 Mbps 1:1) in my company.

When I use speedtest.net or any other test website, speed values are vey poor (1.56 for download, and 2.39 for upload).

So, I claimed Level 3 for not providing the agreed bandwidth, but they said they performed a "saturation test" in which bandwidth reaches 10 Mbps. They also said their test is accurate because it doesn't depend on a test server like speedtest.net

**How can I know they are telling the truth?.**

This is the image:

[image: Level3 test report]

This is their report:

```
FastEthernet4 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is PQII_PRO_UEC, address is b838.61ac.b57c (bia b838.61ac.b57c)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 25/255, rxload 25/255
  Encapsulation 802.1Q Virtual LAN, Vlan ID  1., loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 00:42:18
  Input queue: 4/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 335
  Queueing strategy: Class-based queueing
  Output queue: 64/1000/0 (size/max total/drops)
  30 second input rate 10060000 bits/sec, 832 packets/sec
  30 second output rate 10038000 bits/sec, 829 packets/sec
     1085479 packets input, 1634002628 bytes
     Received 220 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     1083785 packets output, 1632163458 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some testing with IPERF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf)
There are public servers on the wiki page.

Tests can be done for UDP and TCP traffic.
This will give you an insight on the speed of your connection.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do another test to speedtest.net or similar from outside your network?  Just connect a laptop directly to the WAN uplink for a moment after hours or something and see what you can get without involving your firewall or anything else behind it.

Answer (score 1):

No one can guarantee bandwidth once it leaves their network. These sorts of line qualification tests are done to server(s) within the ISP network.

I'm not saying you don't have an issue with L3. However, random speedtest sites are not always going to be indicative of reality.